# Xcode file missing from the editors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello guys I am jumping into a really weird problem that most of my files are missing from the Xcode editor. I can still compile and run the app, also all the files are still there in my project folder, but I just cannot see them in the Xcode editor anymore. I can have them back to editor by open each file one by one, however when I close xcode and reopen everything is gone again. Can anyone help me please, this is the picture.[Only few files left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAzcJ.png)

[image]

Comment: What if you just drag and drop them into the side bar again? Specify that you don't want to copy them and you should be fine.

Comment: right click on project and you will see option like `Add Files to "bargo"...` some thing like that and add missing file to your project it was in your project  but not project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable the recent view button at bottom of xcode.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer, it solves my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder from Finder and search for the missing file. Just drag and drop the files in yor xcode.
If files are missing from the project directory then you need to create the new files with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not adding those files just by reference. You must copy it with correct target.